# VBA Code to autohighlight modified cells?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently using this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then Range("B9:AE53").Interior.Color = xlNone
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B9:AE53")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("B9:AE53"))
        Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

Autohighlight only works when I manually edit (or F2 then enter) the cells in B9:AE53. I was hoping for something that would change the cell color if I edit the data in the orders sheet (reference for B9:AE53).

Was also hoping to transfer the event from B1 to a command button.

Comment: Much too broad a question. Start by recording a macro where you perform the tasks you want to perform automatically and then asking questions about what the generated code does.

Comment: Conditional formatting?

Comment: Tried it but it wont really do what I need it to do :/

Comment: Your question is very broad and does not have enough information for us to help you.

Comment: Your `Worksheet_Change` code checks if the cell you changed (`Target`) is in range of `B9:AE53` (`If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B9:AE53")) Is Nothing Then`). If this is not what you are looking for, you need to rewrite this part.

Comment: @EganWolf what part of the worksheet_change code should I alter if my reference range is in sheet4 range(A:G)?

Comment: @kemichan I just noticed, that your code is changing the color of `Target` cell. Then, I don't understand what do you want to achieve. Please edit your question or create a new one, as this one has an answer already, and be more specific in describing your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the second part of your question, the one where you wish to reset the cell colors to nothing, to be executed by a button.

Change the code to this:

```
Sub CleanUp()
Range("B9:AE53").Interior.Color = xlNone
End Sub
```

Then add a button via the Forms Control Button in the developer toolbar and asign the above macro to it. This will clean up the area. Once you specifiy what the desired outcome is for the first part of you question I might be able to help with that.